# infiniteScroll + masorny are crashed

Tags: javascript, crash, infinite-scroll, masonry

I've been using infiniteScroll + masonry. infiniteScroll and masonry are good.
I could make infiniteScroll easily. and I could place elements in optimal position based on available vertical space.

But, I face a problem.
The more I append contents, the more scroll is so slow. finally, browser is crashed.

What should I do?
Somebody help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

The Masonry and infiniteScroll are good libraries.

However, if you consider long contents and high performance, you must consider what to use them.

Because infinteScroll and Masonry steadily increase DOM.
infinite scroll only appends contents. Therefore, if contents are long, scrolling is so slow and the browser is blocked.
You should use DOM recycle structure.

I recommended [eg.infiniteGrid](https://github.com/naver/egjs). eg.infiniteGrid keeps a number of DOMs always.

Checks out this video: [eg.infiniteGrid benchmark](https://youtu.be/NyFtShC2yq8): append item performance